# n+1 for counting items in a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

(Using rails 4)

I have an `Event` model that `has_many` subscriptions. In the list of events, I display the number of subscriptions. To do this in my view for every event I have:

```
event.subscriptions.count
```

However, this causes a performance hit because for every event a subsequent query is performed to obtain the `subscriptions` count.

To fix this I thought to get all the subscriptions, something along these lines:

```
subscription_count = Event.all.map { |e| {e.id => e.subscriptions.count} }
```

Then instead of performing a query for every event, I would simply look up the `event id` in the `subscription_count` hash. However, this obviously still performs all the queries separately. Is there a way to perform some aggregate query to do the job in one go?

Thanks!

Comment: You can set a counter_cache column in your event table for the subscription. another way you can fetch events like Event.includes(:subscription) and in the view you can use e.subscription.size instead of count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a counter_cache column in your event table for the subscription. another way you can fetch events like Event.includes(:subscription) and in the view you can use e.subscription.size instead of count also you can check this link also 
if you only need the count of the associated model
http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: Your includes(:subscriptions) won't work, see comment below. However, the suggestion about using counter_cache was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth like:

```
@events = Event.joins('LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscription.event_id = event.id').group('events.id').select('events.*, COUNT(subscriptions.id) AS number_of_subscriptions')
```

And then inside the view use:

```
event.number_of_subscriptions
```

Comment: I tried that, it will just fetch more data but does not solve the n+1 issue for the subscriptions count.